# JRE default installed on Windows

Tags: java

I don't know java so, forgive me for this simple question. So in windows by default jre file is installed, and its outdated(for me). I found that: *" jre is the runtime portion of Java software, which is all you need to run it in your Web browser"*. But I don't understand that *"...which is all you need to run it in your Web browser* So do we really need jre in our windows, and if we don't why is it installed by default?

Comment: I don't think there's any "default" JRE on Windows.  Generally java-based apps install a copy since they need it.  And Java/JRE no longer has anything to do with your web browser.  They parted ways long ago.  Not sure what you're quoting, but it seems dated.

Comment: And do I need jre on my Windows and can I remove it

Comment: Like I said, if you have JRE on your system, probably when you installed some application that needs it, it installed JRE.  So that application would break if you removed JRE.